# Algorithm2e does not allow nested if

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I was trying to put a nested if in algorithm area like this:

```
          \If{$isContentMethod(\mathcal{M})$}{
            $URI \leftarrow getURI(SubCG, \mathcal{M})$\;
            \If($URI \in \mathcal{P}_c$){
                $Permission \leftarrow getPermission(URI, \mathcal{P}_c)$\;
                $\mathcal{B}.add(Permission, URI, Entrypoints)$ \;
            }
         }
```

But LaTeX keep giving me errors:

```
! Argument of \algocf@Ifmain has an extra }.
<inserted text>
\par
l.69 }
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you post a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? It is really of help to answer you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) does supply an `\If(..)`-style conditional (for commenting), you're probably after `\If{..}{...}` inside your nested if. The reason for the failure is because the `\If(..)`-style usage requires more arguments than you are currently supplying.

Mere's a MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\begin{document} 
\begin{algorithm}
\If{$isContentMethod(\mathcal{M})$}{
  $URI \leftarrow getURI(SubCG, \mathcal{M})$\;
  \If{$URI \in \mathcal{P}_c$}{% Don't use `\If(..)`
    $Permission \leftarrow getPermission(URI, \mathcal{P}_c)$\;
    $\mathcal{B}.add(Permission, URI, Entrypoints)$ \;
  }
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Also consider using the [`amsmath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) that provides `\text{...}` for setting some of your text-related math content.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made a mistake by using () instead of {}